# Laravel 4 on Debian 6

Tags: php, debian, laravel

My server is using Debian 6 and I would use Laravel 4 for my websites, but for this Linux Release PHP 5.3.3 is the latest version supported.

I really want to use Laravel, how can i make this possible?

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/q/404815

Comment: I think not. Because on Debian 6 Squeezy the last official relaease of PHP is 5.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.3.3 maybe was de last estable, not de last version supported. You can install manually following this guide: http://davejamesmiller.com/blog/installing-php-5-4-on-debian-6-squeeze

Comment: You know if can be problems with Parallels Plesk Panel 11.0.9? My provider told me that can be problems ...